# AWS Pinpoint SMS - Message Attributes/Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to implement a SMS module using AWS Pinpoint, but I can't seem to find a way to get it working how I would like. I've tried other SMS vendors, like Twilio, that let you attach metadata to the message being sent. This metadata is returned on the response, so it's useful to be able read the metadata and process the response. AWS is cheaper on the price per message, and since I already use it for other modules I want to stick with Amazon. I've been reading over the documentation for SMS for a few days and I can't really find the answer that I'm looking for and I'm starting to think Pinpoint may not be the service for this. I see that SQS and SNS seem to support having message attributes whereas Pinpoint really uses the keyword for 2 way messaging.

Question to the people who use AWS for SMS, is there any way to attach custom attributes that will be returned with the response to the message?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Pinpoint doesn't support message attributes currently.

The service you might want reviewing is [Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-attributes.html) or [Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html) which supports message attributes as you've noticed where each message can have up to 10 attributes.